# Why did this index fund jump almost 20,000% in 2017?

Tags: investing, index-fund

I am looking at [Vanguard Pacific ex-Japan Stock Index Fund GBP Dist (0P0000KM1Z.L)](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000KM1Z.L/chart?p=0P0000KM1Z.L&guccounter=1#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--) on Yahoo Finance.

Between 2017-12-24 and 2017-12-31 it jumped from £200 to £20,376.

[image]

What would have caused such a sharp increase?

Comment: It's either a reverse split or bad data.  No fund jumps 100x overnight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [The Financial Times](https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=IE00B523L081:GBP) quote page

[image]

It would seem to me the Yahoo data went bad for some reason. It's quoting pence instead of pounds?

To confirm, I went right to [Vanguard](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-pacific-ex-japan-stock-index-fund-gbp-dist) and saw -

[image]

Which confirms the FT quoting. So, to the 2 comments, yes, bad data, confirmed by 2 sources.